# Change labels in Javascript

Tags: javascript, shiny

I am having the following function:

```
Mois <-
   "$(function() {
     setTimeout(function(){
       var vals = [0];
   vals.push(12);
   vals.push(18);
   vals.push(24);
   vals.push(36);
   vals.push(60);
   vals.push(120);
       $('#mois').data('ionRangeSlider').update({'values':vals})
     }, 5)})"
```

Which I use in Shiny application to control the step of the SliderInput. That gives me:

[image]

How can I change the numbers. I am having months and I want to label the scale in years.

Thanks

Comment: Yes sorry, a JavaScript

Comment: I dont understand how it relates to shiny. Why would you need the code above when you could specify all that within `sliderInput()`?

Comment: Because I don't want to change the values of the sliderInput. In fact I use them in many functions after that in order to make some estimations

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891645/ionrangeslider-assign-labels-to-values) does what you are looking for.