# How to assign labels on a range slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```html
<div class="range-wrap">
  <input id="range" type="range" name="range" min="3" max="20" value="10" step="1">
  <label id="rangevalue">10</label>
</div>
```

I to need to create range slider, where the values below 7 are labelled modest, 7 to 15 as moderate and anything above labelled as extensive. How I do add these labels to my range slide?

Comment: Check whether this helps <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891645/ionrangeslider-assign-labels-to-values>

Comment: Does this answer your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224856/jquery-ui-slider-labels-under-slider ?

Comment: @Santa thanks for the suggestion I have looked at that before, but what I need to do is a little different. The labels are supposed to compass multiple value so it the case of modest the values 3 to 7 should fall under that

Comment: @Vvictory thanks for the reference, I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea will to be just simply get the value of existing slider and based on the value, do an *if statement*.

And to get the value when someone moves the slider, you can use `oninput`.

Try this:

**First Answer Without The Partition**

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var display = document.getElementById("display");
var getVal = slider.value;

numVal.innerHTML = getVal; // If you don't want the number to be displayed, delete this. This is to show at which number the label will change

if(getVal<7) {
  display.innerHTML = "Modest";
}

if(getVal>=7 && getVal<=15) {
  display.innerHTML = "Moderate";
}

if(getVal>15){
  display.innerHTML = "Extensive";
}

slider.oninput = function() {
  numVal.innerHTML = this.value;// If you don't want the number to be displayed, delete this. This is to show at which number the label will change
  
  var getVal = this.value;
  if(getVal<7) {
    display.innerHTML = "Modest";
  }
  
  if(getVal>=7 && getVal<=15) {
    display.innerHTML = "Moderate";
  }
  
  if(getVal>15){
    display.innerHTML = "Extensive";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="range-wrap"> 
  <input id="range" type="range" name="range" min="3" max="20" value="10" step="1">
  <label id="display"></label>
  <p id="numVal"></p> <!-- If you don't want the number to be displayed, delete this. This is to show at which number the label will change -->
</div>
```

ps: I've added comments in the code to hide the number if you don't want it. The numbers are there so you can see the change is happening at the right number. Delete the commented code accordingly to hide number values from displaying.

**Updated Answer: (with partition)**

You can use child elements to create a bar and push it on top of the slider using *absolute* and *relative* position. Its just a simple CSS trick.

The idea is to set a width for your range. Then, create 2 divs that looks like bars using *border-right* and then absolutely position it to your parent (which would be the range input)

Try this:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var display = document.getElementById("display");
var getVal = slider.value;

numVal.innerHTML = getVal; // If you don't want the number to be displayed, delete this. This is to show at which number the label will change

if(getVal<7) {
  display.innerHTML = "Modest";
}

if(getVal>=7 && getVal<=15) {
  display.innerHTML = "Moderate";
}

if(getVal>15){
  display.innerHTML = "Extensive";
}

slider.oninput = function() {
  numVal.innerHTML = this.value;// If you don't want the number to be displayed, delete this. This is to show at which number the label will change
  
  var getVal = this.value;
  if(getVal<7) {
    display.innerHTML = "Modest";
  }
  
  if(getVal>=7 && getVal<=15) {
    display.innerHTML = "Moderate";
  }
  
  if(getVal>15){
    display.innerHTML = "Extensive";
  }
}
```

```css
#range-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=range] {
  width: 200px;
}

#range-bars {
  width: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 47px;
}

#range-bars-two {
  width: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 157px;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-wrap"> 
  <input id="range" type="range" name="range" min="3" max="20" value="10" step="1">
  <label id="display"></label>
  <p id="numVal"></p> <!-- If you don't want the number to be displayed, delete this. This is to show at which number the label will change -->
  <div id="range-bars"></div>
  <div id="range-bars-two"></div>
</div>
```

ps: there was a slight error in the *if statement* and I have made the changes to this answer plus the snippet 1 answer.

Comment: Is there a way to have the labels on the range slider all at once to so the user can know what values fall in the categories?

Comment: I don't understand, hmm you mean it should display as, eg; Moderate (3-7) ? Or, eg; Moderate(5) if the value happens to be 5. ?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear earlier. What I mean is it already shown that from the beginning that Modest (3 to 6), Moderate (7 to 15) and Extensive (16 to 20) I want to create visual partition between these three categories. There is a line down the values 7 and to 15 to show where the categories begin and end.

Comment: Ok I've updated the answer, please do check if this is what you want.

Comment: Np, glad it helped! Go ahead and change those CSS to style it according to your liking..